# Objected-oriented programming - When to add a new class?

Tags: oop, class, object

I'm still very much learning the basics of Objective-C, but I'm still trying to come to grips with objects and classes.

I understand the usual analogy: "Car" is the class and "Ford" is the object of that class, with certain properties like "color" and "year manufactured". What I don't understand is how this can be used in practical terms.

Let's say I'm creating a basic web browser with all of the usual functions (load the page, display the page, add page as a bookmark, print the page). I can't seem to think of an application like this outside of simple variables and methods. You know, you click a button and it calls a method, which manipulates some variables. I also can't help but think this would be one *very* long page of code, so I understand that it would help to break it up.

I'm sorry if this is all very vague, I just find it difficult to comprehend when I should be creating new classes and when it's okay to just add another method to the class I'm already working in.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of hints to a new class

- When you can name something,  if there is a concept in your code that you can name, its a good candidate for a new class.
- If you have several functions that manipulate the same variables.   If you end up passing the same variables to several functions, then quite likely those variables and functions should be a class
- Extract good functions from any complicated code.  This should be your first priority, good functions that do one thing well.  Then see if functions all relate to one concept and group together in a class.
- You have a lot of code that kind of does the same thing but handles different variations.   Then you have an abstraction / interface and several subclasses.

Basically, don't be scared to make a class.... just take a punt and do it.   If it seems that the class is just making things awkward.  You just learnt something.  So you then need to rethink the design and find another way of breaking things down / abstracting things.   Its all about trying things out.

Start looking at design patterns and you'll start seeing some common ways other people handle awkward situations a bit more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Class is not limited to concrete things as you mentioned Car, Ford. It can be used to map abstract things. At least, in your case Browser itself, Page and Bookmark can all be classes. Object composition is a good practice in OO programming.

Comment: So, for example, it would be satisfactory to name a class "Print", and inside this class have methods such as "changePageOrientation" and "showPrintPreview"? Then in other classes if we wanted to print something we would create an instance of the "Print" class and provide those methods with the relevant information (e.g. the data to print)?

Answer (score 0):

You should first analyze your domain, the data with which your site will work. Just write it on the paper, extract nouns and think whether you can present them as separate objects. In your example you can create a Car class if you have a car shop site. Soon you will be able to extract different types of equipments for that car and other related classes. It's just the matter of thinking in terms of objects but not methods firstly. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model), may be that will give you more information. After all you probably work with database that itself implies to split data into entities. Probably much of that entities have methods also. Look also at [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to get basic knowledge of how can you represent a Car on the web page. I hope it will help you a little.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in terms of procedural languages like C.  That's not bad, as there are all kinds of uses for procedural languages, but that's not the way you want to think with an object oriented language like Objective-C.

In a procedural language, you have some data, and you have some code.  The two are separate.  While you can have functions that operate on data, those functions can be anywhere in your source, as can the data.  There isn't a clear delineation of responsibilities unless you take care to design your program a certain way.  One way to delineate things is to write C code that comes out looking an awful lot like object oriented code.

In OOP, you have data and the code that operates on that data.  The code and data go together.  The data is your class' member variables, and the code is your class' member functions.

You can compose large objects by combining objects of simpler classes.  For example a car would contain objects of class engine, body, four objects of class tire and so on.

Objects can also connect to each other by having one object use another.  A driver object would use a car, or a car would use a road.

Object oriented programming is not the Silver Bullet we have sought since computers were invented.  It's just a good way of organizing your code.  As you get more experienced, you will quickly find that object oriented code can be just as much a rat's nest as procedural code.  If that's the case, you're not thinking about your problem right.

Answer (score 0):

You create a class when you want to represent some entity. In your example you have mentioned you are creating a web browser which does tasks like load the page, display the page, add page as a bookmark, print the page....as you can see here things are revolving around the page....so you can make the page a class and add various methods that operate on it. If you observe popular browsers, for each new page you want to open a new tab or a new window is instantiated....you can derive form the same.

So....

- Create a class whenever you want to represent an entity which you
  would want to act upon.
- Create a function when you want to do a
  task.

Happy Coding !